# swift: Auto-Renewable Subscriptions

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть код для встроенной покупки (Non-Consumable). Я тестировал этот код в реальном приложении, и код работает нормально. Теперь я хочу создать новую встроенную покупку в другом приложении (Auto-Renewable Subscriptions). Я создал покупку в iTunesConnect. И у меня есть вопрос.

Могу ли я взять и использовать код из приложения с покупкой (Non-Consumable) и вставить в приложении для (Auto-Renewable Subscriptions)? Мне просто нужно изменить идентификатор покупки? Или я должен добавить что-то новое в свой код, чтобы работала (Auto-Renewable Subscriptions)?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас должен быть код для покупки и код для восстановления покупки. Если всё это есть для покупки Non-Consumable, то код подойдет, т.к. покупки идут по идентификатору.